# How to Manually Set up a Library in GitHub for Use in CoqIDE?

Tags: coq, coqide

I need to use a library in GitHub different from Coq's standard library. But I do not know how to manually set it up so that I can use it in CoqIDE.

I need to use this [library](https://github.com/mit-plv/kami/tree/master/Kami/Lib) in CoqIDE. I have downloaded and saved the folder to my computer, but when I open CoqIDE and write "Require Import StringEq", where StringEq is the name of a Coq file from the library, I get the error message "Unable to locate library StringEq".

Is there any way I can manually set up this libray so that I can use it with CoqIDE? (There are no instructions on the READme file on the library's GitHub page.)

Answer (score 2):

The official usage seems to be add kami to the `$COQPATH` environment variable.

On Linux, add this line to `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whatever initialization your shell uses and restart your shell:

```
export COQPATH=/path/to/kami:$COQPATH
# That path must be so that `/path/to/kami/Kami/Lib/StringEq.v` is the path to `StringEq` for example
```

---

Below is another way I am using.
[It doesn't seem like intended usage](https://coq.discourse.group/t/proposal-a-custom-build-tool-for-coq-projects/239/6). Maybe I'm just resistant to changing my ways, but I also prefer being explicit about my dependencies, and I'm not sure the `COQPATH` environment variable makes it as easy to have different versions of the same library in different projects.

Add a `_CoqProject` that tells CoqIDE where to find kami.

Here's an example layout:

```
kami/           # The Kami repository
myproject/      # Your workspace
  _CoqProject
  theories/
    MyProject.v
```

Where `myproject/_CoqProject` contains:

```
-Q ../kami/Kami Kami
# and possibly other options
```

---

Either way, remember to build Kami:

```
cd kami/
make
```

Comment: I was told that the dependencies were not supposed to be listed in the _CoqProject file, but instead chosen using the COQPATH environment variable (see [this discussion](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4990#issuecomment-344672293) or [this post](https://coq.discourse.group/t/proposal-a-custom-build-tool-for-coq-projects/239/6)).

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Thanks, I'll make a new answer!

Comment: Actually I'm stuck at explaining where to put the `export COQPATH` line (because nobody wants to have to fix COQPATH everyday), there seems to be quite some variety depending on your shell (`.bashrc`? `.zshrc`?) or OS (Windows?).

Comment: So I can't explain this workflow without it becoming a tutorial on how to manage your environment variables, which I believe is going to be lost on most new users anyway. I may be missing something obvious. The inconvenience is compounded by the fact that some existing libraries do not follow the right structure for this: they put their files in `theories/` or `src/`. This could arguably be considered a bug in those libs, but it is not quite clear to me that this envvar-based workflow is best in the first place. So I'll give this task up to someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: Maybe the simplest answer is then to install the dependency in the `user-contrib`sub-directory of the Coq installation that is always in the Coq path. This is done by the `install` target of the Makefile generated by `coq_makefile`. This can be seen as polluting your system, though.

Comment: I added a `$COQPATH` solution to my answer. Let's hope that will just work for OP and other people, or it will encourage improvements to documentation and tooling. I feel like it merely hides a very deep rabbit hole but I could also be overthinking this.